# how can i use two associations at once in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i'am using cakephp 2.x
i have two tables USERS and JOBS in my database, 
in users table i save two types of users job candidate and company in this situation i found my self facing two relations between the tables :

1. (1,n)users can add (0,1)jobs. (user role here is Company)
2. many (1,n)users can apply to many (1,n)jobs. ( Candidate)

can i use belongsTo and HABTM(hasAndBelongsToMany) at once between the two models ?
like this :

1. Job model

   ```
   Class Job extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo=array(
     'User'=> array(
        'className' => 'User',
       'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
       'counterCache'=>true,
       'fields'=>array('id','username','role'),

           )
       );
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany=array('User');
    public $usetable = 'jobs';
   ```
2. User Model

   ```
   Class User extends AppModel{
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany=array('Job');
   ```

how to retrieve data depending on the first or the second context
1- show all jobs of company.
2- show users applies.

Comment: why not separate users and companies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but the two associations need different aliases. So you could refer to an `User` appling for a `Job` as an `Applicant`:-

```
class Job extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User'=> array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'counterCache' => true,
            'fields' => array('id', 'username', 'role'),
        )
    );

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Applicant' => array(
            'className' => 'User'
        )
    );

}
```

Note that you need to tell Cake that the `Applicant` uses the `User` model via the `className` property. For your `belongsTo` association you don't need to specify the `className` for the `User` as it is the same as the alias is the same as the model name but I have left it in for clarity.

You also don't need to specify `$usetable = 'jobs` as this is implied by using the correct naming conventions.